# Facebook - Prevent tokens from expiring

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Developing an app that uses Facebook permissions.

According to the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens/get-long-lived/

"If no requests are made, the token will expire after about 60 days"

So, can I just setup a Cron to read data every 30 days from the Facebook account using the token and the token will never expire?